# Error : Sox has exited with error code 1. How can i this error debug?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-functions, sox

I am testing recongnize.js among Google speech api.
But now I have an error related to the Sox.
How can I debug?

it is error.

```
Listening, press Ctrl+C to stop.
sox has exited with error code 1.

Enable debugging with the environment variable DEBUG=record.
```

I've installed all of the versions 14.1.1 and 14.1.2 and entered them into $Path.

I need your help

Comment: It's unclear what Sox has to do with the Google API. You should add a reproducible, minimal example code to your question. But I would definitely do what the error says: set environment variable `DEBUG=record`.

Comment: Are you getting this error in Cloud Functions? Could you please explain briefly your issue? And Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please have a look into the [Cloud Functions Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var) for the Environment variables.